# Undefined columns selected after add a new column

Tags: r, error-handling

I met a problem. I would like to delete the first row and add a new column to the exsiting data. Then I want to select out the new column with other existing columns in the data (i.e., "GEO.id2", "GEO.display.label", and  "HD01_VD08"). Commands are As below:

```
c08<-read.csv("ACS_08_1YR_B23001_with_ann.csv", header = TRUE)
c08<-c08[-1,]
c08$Year<-rep(2008,nrow(c08)) 
new<-c08[,c("GEO.id2","GEO.display.label","Year", "HD01_VD08")]
```

But I get the error message:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(c08, , c("GEO.id2", "GEO.display.label", "Year",  : 
undefined columns selected
```

I don't know how to solve this problem. Is it the problem of "$" in the command?

```
c08$Year<-rep(2008,nrow(c08))
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: No, the `$` line is fine. The error is in the `[` command. Look at `names(c08)` and make sure you don't have any typos in the column names you've specified.

Comment: FYI, for a constant value you can just use `c08$Year <- 2008`, it will be automatically repeated.

Comment: @Gregor  Emmmm, I checked the names again, the names are correct. And I also tried your way to create the Year (i.e., c08$Year <- 2008), but got the same error message....

Comment: Right, the year thing is just an FYI. **That line has nothing to do with your error.**

Comment: At this point you say all the columns `"GEO.id2","GEO.display.label","Year", "HD01_VD08"` exist in your data, and R says they don't. Please make your example reproducible by sharing the output of `dput(droplevels(head(c09)))`, that way we can see your actual data structure and  copy it into our R sessions. Just edit the `dput` results into your question.